# How to create an Akka Actor given the class name

Tags: scala, akka

I would like to create an Akka actor by using the class name, as shown.
I've tried many variations of system.actorOf(new Props(theProcessor.getClass), name = "Test"), 
but I just cannot get this to work. Any idea in creating an Actor from the class loader

```
package com.test

import akka.actor.{Props, Actor, ActorRef, ActorSystem}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
   ActorFromString("Test")
  }
}

object ActorFromString {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("Test")
  def apply(name: String): ActorRef = {
    val className = "com.test." + name + "Processor"
    val theProcessor: Actor = Class.forName(className).newInstance().asInstanceOf[Actor]
    system.actorOf(new Props(theProcessor.getClass), name = "Test")
  }
}

class TestProcessor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case data => println("processing data")
  }
}

Exception in thread "main" akka.actor.ActorInitializationException:
You cannot create an instance of [com.test.TestProcessor] explicitly using the constructor (new).
You have to use one of the factory methods to create a new actor. Either use:
'val actor = context.actorOf(Props[MyActor])'        (to create a supervised child actor from    within an actor), or
'val actor = system.actorOf(Props(new MyActor(..)))' (to create a top level actor from the   ActorSystem)
at akka.actor.ActorInitializationException$.apply(Actor.scala:166)
at akka.actor.Actor$class.$init$(Actor.scala:377)
at com.test.TestProcessor.<init>(ActorFromString.scala:20)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at  sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:374)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
at com.test.ActorFromString$.apply(ActorFromString.scala:15)
at com.test.Main$.main(ActorFromString.scala:7)
at com.test.Main.main(ActorFromString.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

Process finished with exit code 143
```

Comment: I realise that my question may not be very clear. The crux here is to pass in a name and construct an actor from it. The name is not known ahead of time, but is from the set of possible class names. The test example here is just one class "TestProcessor", there could be another called "Test2Processor", etc...

Comment: I think I've solved it. I need to construct the actor inside the Props thing.system.actorOf(Props(Class.forName(className).newInstance().asInstanceOf[Actor]), name = device)

Answer (score 7):

You could use the Java API (just for the Props instantiation):

```
val myActor = system.actorOf( 
  new Props( Class.forName( "myActorClassName" ).asInstanceOf[Class[Actor]] ) 
)
```

The important part is the `new` keyword. If you ommit it, you will use the Scala API instead, which does not allow instantiation by class.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you want to use the same ClassLoader as the one that is used by your ActorSystem,
so this is easily solved with a custom Akka Extension (Warning, not actually compiled but you'll get the gist of it)

```
import akka.actor.{ Extension, ExtensionId, ExtensionIdProvider, ExtendedActorSystem, DynamicAccess }
// This will be instantiated once per ActorSystem instance
class Reflection(access: DynamicAccess) extends Extension {
  // Loads the Class with the provided Fully Qualified Class Name using the given DynamicAccess
  // Throws exception if it fails to load
  def actorClassFor(fqcn: String) = access.getClassFor[Actor](fqcn).get
}
// This is how we access the Reflection extension, you can view it as an ActorSystemLocal
object Reflect extends ExtensionId[Reflection] with ExtensionIdProvider {
  override def lookup = Reflect
  override def createExtension(system: ExtendedActorSystem) = new Reflection(system.dynamicAccess)
}
// Load the extension if not already loaded, return the instance for this ActorSystem and call the actorClassFor
system.actorOf(Props(Reflect(system).actorClassFor("com.test." + name + "Processor"))
```

Answer (score 4):

(As indicated in the stacktrace) you have to use either

- `system.actorOf(Props[TestProcessor])`   (no `new` keyword, you pass a type)
- or `system.actorOf(Props(new TestProcessor()))`  (`new` keyword, you pass an instance)

Comment: To nitpick, you don't pass an instance, you pass a by-name parameter that will be executed every time a new actor instance is needed.

Comment: @EndreVarga true. The apply method signature is `def apply(creator: ⇒ Actor): Props = default.withCreator(creator)`. The argument is a thunk that creates and instance of an actor.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get a Props from a String then you can get an actor from a String. Here is how to get a Props from a String:

```
Props.apply(Class.forName( "myActorClassName" ).asInstanceOf[Class[Actor]])
```

I put this up because none of the other answers use `Props.apply` - a relatively recent enhancement to Akka. It is easy to pass in constructor arguments, for instance the current actorRef, for example:

```
def selfActorRef = context.self
val gateKeeperRef = context.actorOf(
  Props.apply(Class.forName(findGateKeeperName).asInstanceOf[Class[Actor]],
  selfActorRef)
)
```