# Any way to avoid defining a props method in an Akka companion object?

Tags: scala, akka

I am working with an established code base in Akka and I am seeing this pattern a lot:

```
class Bar(a: A, b: B, c: C) extends Actor {
   // body of actor
}

object Bar {
   def props(a: A, b: B, c: C) = Props(new Bar(a = a, b = b, c = c)
}
```

But the props method feels ugly like a getter/setter in Java. Is there a better way to do this?

I thought it would be possible to create the actor directly e.g.

```
var child = context.actorOf(Props(new Bar(a, b, c))
```

As this is not much more complicated than the version using props:

```
var child =  context.actorOf(Bar.Props(a, b, c))
```

However if I understand this post on [Deprecation of Closures Taking Props](http://letitcrash.com/post/49001044816/2-2-spotlight-deprecation-of-closure-taking-props) then this is bad practice. Instead they advocate using:

```
var child = context.actorOf(Props(classOf[Bar], a, b, c))
```

But then this suffers from refactoring problems as Ryan outlines below?

Comment: Putting the `Props` in a companion object keeps it closer to the definition of the actor it constructs and makes it easier to refactor that actor later on since you won't have multiple `Props` lying around for the same actor.

Comment: Hi Ryan! I observe exactly the opposite. This construct makes refactoring worse because now I need to change all the constructors AND the props methods. Unless there are other constraints here I don't understand? Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: You've misunderstood.  Your first example is what I was advocating, not the one you added to your post.

Comment: Here's a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675227/how-to-create-an-akka-actor-given-the-class-name

Comment: Good to have the source of the advice in the original AKKA documentation - it's here http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/scala/actors.html#Recommended_Practices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides keeping the `Props` creation closer to the actor's class, it also avoids accidentally closing over an actor's `this` reference, as would happen if you used `Props(new MyActor("foo"))` inside another actor.

See the [most recent reference guide section on `Props`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#Props):

> This also avoids the pitfalls associated with using the
>   Props.apply(...) method which takes a by-name argument, since within a
>   companion object the given code block will not retain a reference to
>   its enclosing scope.

If you really don't want to use the companion object `.props` and want to create the `Props` inside another actor then you should use this version of the `Props` creator for safety:

```
def apply(clazz: Class[_], args: Any*)
```

For example:

```
context.actorOf(Props(classOf[MyActor], "foo"))
```

The obvious disadvantage is that it doesn't provide type checking of the parameters.

Answer (score 3):

The main reason to keep it closer to the class is because reflection is involved and you don't want reflective calls lying around all over your code base, because one change in the constructor of your actor could break things at runtime and you want that stack trace to be as close to your problem as possible (BTW, you don't seem to use the reflective way of Actor construction in your example).

**EDIT**

```
object MyActor {
  def props(param: Int): Props = Props(classOf[MyActor], param)
}

class MyActor(param: Int) extends Actor {
  def receive = ...
}
```

If you were to change the constructor of `MyActor` to accept e.g. an additional parameter, like so:

```
class MyActor(param: Int, param2: String) extends Actor { ... }
```

your code would compile just fine, but at runtime the reflection API would not be able to find a public constructor which matches the call from `Props(classOf[MyActor], param)` so an exception will be thrown and you will see a stack trace in the log. You want that stack trace to be as close to the root of the problem as possible, so you can find/fix the problem faster. If everyone were to use the `props` factory method, the only place where all your stack traces (if any) would lead you to would be the definition of, well, the `props` factory method.

Comment: Hi agilesteel. Sorry I don't get it - please can you give some example code? I am guessing normally you use reflection when you don't know what the actor type is until runtime. That's not the case here.